# How to insert a map of objects into a Postgres Database?

Tags: java, postgresql, function, hashmap

Given an object (MainObject) containing a map of objects such as

```
public class MainObject {
  private String name;
  private Map<String, Policy> policy policies;  
}

public class Policy {
  private Status status;
  private String expiry = null;
  private Operation operation = null;
  }
```

How could I persist both MainObject and the inner policies into a PostgreSql database using JDBC?

For a map<String, String> I would use:

```
Connection conn = DatabaseConnectionProvider.getConnection(appConfig);
CallableStatement stmt = conn.prepareCall("{call insert_object(?,?)}")
stmt.setString(1, name);
Array arrayL = conn.createArrayOf("VARCHAR", labelArray.toArray();
stmt.setString(2, arrayL);
stmt.executeQuery();
```

The function would be something like (I am unsure about the format of policies to be passed)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_object(
in_name VARCHAR(255),
policies VARCHAR(255)[][]
)
RETURNS BOOLEAN
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN

INSERT INTO public.object_table(
    name
) VALUES (
    in_name
);


// INSERT POLICIES
END
$$;
```

I have a database table policies containing:

```
create table policies (
   ObjectName VARCHAR(255)
   status VARCHAR(255),
   expiry VARCHAR(255),
   operation VARCHAR(255)
);
```

and another table for the mainObject itself as:

```
create table mainobject (
   id INT,
   name VARCHAR(255)
);
```

How could I proceed with a Map<String, Object> ?

Thanks!

Comment: It depends what are you using to connect to the database, JDBC, JPA, Jooq, other. The question is unclear.

Comment: You should create a database representation for these policies, is not that simple has "insert object", you can serialize it as a string and recover it later but that's not a good idea.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback, I added more details about the configuration and the issue itself. Hopefully, that would help clarifying

Answer (score 0):

I finally created a new database type for those objects:

```
CREATE TYPE policy AS (job_name VARCHAR(255), status VARCHAR(255), expiry TIMESTAMP, operation VARCHAR(255));
```

Then adapted the function to use that TYPE:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION insert_object(
in_name VARCHAR(255),
in_policies policy[]
)
RETURNS VOID
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS $$
BEGIN
INSERT INTO public.object_table(
name
) VALUES (
in_name
);

INSERT INTO public.policies (job_name , expiry , status, operation)
  SELECT in_name , p.expiry, p.status, p.operation
  FROM unnest(in_policies) AS p;
  RETURN;
END
$$;
```